# Issues with Text

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to game development. I made a quick little 10-second Android project with Unity that just shows a few UI texts on-screen. It appears fine when I run it in Unity, but when I put the game onto my phone, the texts appear as pink blocks. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Here's what happens:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bad font size, did you check the styles?

Comment: I wasn't aware that could make that big of a difference. I'll check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several hints:

- Maybe some material are missing (this magenta color appears when Material is missing).
- Maybe it is just some resolution issue (different resolution in game mode in the Unity editor than on your android device)

To fix the second point, you can set the Unity game mode's resolution to fit your Android device screen size by clicking the drop down menu under the "Game" tab (next to the scale slider). If you are using UI elements, you also have to set your Canvas Scaler to "Scale with screen size and giving him your Android device screen size.

Comment: It was the first one. I added a material and now it's working fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: no pb :) you can set this question as resolved then ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Case of broken connection of prefab.

This colour appears in Unity in case of missing resources. Either you've added a Font to it which is deleted or You've created a prefab of this text which is deleted (possible case).

Comment: I'm not using a prefab and I'm just using the default font. Is that the issue?